# How can I dynamically update a menu item title with user search history on Android Studio?

Tags: android, menuitem

I'm working with this Api project.

This is in a menu and I'm using android studio for the project

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/SH1"
    android:title="@string/app_name"/>
```

I would like to have that "app_name" be word that I would pull from the search history of the user (I was thinking just the last 5 to not make too complicated for me). So there would be 5 items in this menu at most with titles being the search words and in case this results are important, I want it to keep adding new words to this list and erasing the oldest.

How can I achieve this?